# I am not able to sum LYQTD and LYYTD measures data

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am writing LYQTD and LYYTD measures mdx query for show previous year data on the basis of current selected date filter these mdx working quite fine but i am not able to aggregate Last Year to date and Last Quarter to date data.
for ex:- I want to filter data for LYQTD and LYYTD.

these are some sales sample data for different months:

```
Jan 1000
Feb 5000 
Mar 1000 Quarter1
apr 2000
May 4000 
Jun 6000 Quarter2
Jly 8000
Aug 6000
Sep 4500 Quarter3
Oct 6500
Nov 9000
Dec 2000 Quarter4
```

Now i want to aggregate these data on the basis of selected filter
for example i am select Jan month

```
LYQTD LYYTD
1000 1000
```

Now i am selecting Feb month the measures will be aggregated with the previous select filter

```
LYQTD LYYTD
6000 6000
```

Now i am selecting Quarter2 month apr the data will be shows as

```
LYQTD LYYTD
2000 8000
```

My applied queries as mentioned below if there is any solution please help me.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].ActualsLYQTD
AS
AGGREGATE(PARALLELPERIOD([Time].[Time].[Quarter],4,[Time].[Time].CURRENTMEMBER), 
[Measures].[Revenue and Expenses]),
VISIBLE = 1 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Actuals' ;


CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].ActualsLYYTD
AS
AGGREGATE(PARALLELPERIOD([Time].[Time].[Year],1,[Time].[Time].CURRENTMEMBER), 
[Measures].[Revenue and Expenses]),
VISIBLE = 1 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Ac``tuals' ;
```

Comment: It's unclear what's wrong here to me, could you please provide more visual representations?

Comment: Hi  I have requirement, Previous Year YTD till the same date as YTD is returing results for example if the Records in my table is present from 1-jan-2016 to 9-May-2016 then this year YTD will Calculate till 9-May-2016 (this is Working fine ) and Previous year YTD also should calculate till 9-May-2015 from 1-Jan-2015 not for whole year or whole month.my mdx for LYQTD and LYYTD are mentioned above.

Comment: You have to use the ParallelPeriod() function in order to get the same member with parallel parents.

Comment: Hi nice to reply ,But as you see on above query i have already used  ParallelPeriod() function in ActualsLYQTD and ActualsLYYTD measures but i am not able to add selected months data.

Comment: Your next step is to use PeriodToDate().

Comment: Yes ,I got the solution this query is working for me

Comment: CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].ActualsYTD
as
Aggregate(
            PeriodsToDate([Time].[Time].[Year]
                  ,
                  [Time].[Time].CurrentMember
            ),

     [Measures].[Revenue and Expenses])
    ,
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Actuals'  ;

Comment: CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].ActualsLYYTD
 as
(ActualsYTD,  ParallelPeriod([Time].[Time].[Year], 1,
                           [Time].[Time].CurrentMember)) ,



VISIBLE = 1 , 
 
 ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Actuals'  ;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **ParallelPeriod()** to get the same member a year before, **PeriodToDate()** to get a set from the beginning of the year until current member, **Aggregate()** to get aggregated value of [Measures].[Revenue and Expenses] against the set.

```
Aggregate(
    PeriodToDate(
        [Time].[Time].[Year],
        ParallelPeriod(
            [Time].[Time].[Year],
            1,
            [Time].[Time].CurrentMember
        ),
    ), 
    [Measures].[Revenue and Expenses]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your presence,Its really helpful.

Comment: Please check it answered in order to let other people know that your issue is resolved.